# Accordion - one div open at a time - current div closes, then bounces back open

Tags: jquery

I have been banging my head against this code for 2 days now. I need the accordion to have only one section open at a time - got that, as long as you're clicking on a different header - but it won't let me close the open div by clicking its own header - it just bounces back open. I do not want a section to be always open-it needs to close completely. Please help!

```
<div id="accordian-container">
  <div id="section1" class="accordiandiv">
    <header id="header-container1">
      <h3 id="heading1">This is a heading</h3>
    </header>
      <div>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section2" class="accordiandiv">
    <header id="header-container2">
      <h3 id="heading3">This is a heading</h3>
    </header>
      <div>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
  <div id="section3" class="accordiandiv">
    <header id="header-container3">
      <h3 id="heading3">This is a heading</h3>
    </header>
      <div>
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
  </div>
```

This is my script:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordiandiv header').each(function() {
    var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = tis.next('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
    answerAll = $('.accordiandiv').children('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
    tis.click(function() {
      state = !state;
      answerAll.slideUp(state);
      $('.accordiandiv').nextAll('header.active').removeClass('active');
      answer.slideToggle(state);
      tis.toggleClass('active', state);
    });
  });
});
```

### Here is the live site with the accordion working but without only one div open at a time.

http://hills.ccsf.edu/~csmith70/16minclubtest/ask-wendy.html

Please note that some of the headers need to have a background-color change happen on .active. Here is script running on this page.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.accordiandiv header').each(function() {
    var tis = $(this), state = false, answer = tis.next('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
    answerAll = $('.accordiandiv').children('div').hide().css('height','auto').slideUp();
    tis.click(function() {
      state = !state;
      answer.slideToggle(state);
      tis.toggleClass('active', state);
    });
  });
});
```

##

Also please know that the is far more inside each header>div than just paragraph tags - there are also other divs, img, and more accordions.

Comment: where is answer defined?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reduced it get rid of the looping

**UPDATED**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordiandiv p').hide();

    $('.accordiandiv').on('click', function () {
        $('.accordiandiv p').slideUp(200, "linear", function () {
            $('.accordiandiv h3').removeClass('active');
        });        

        var isVisible = $(this).find('p').is(':visible');

        if (!isVisible) {
            $(this).find('p').slideDown(200, "linear", function () {
                $(this).closest('.accordiandiv').find('h3').addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });    
});
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/9TT2t/3/)**:

Comment: you can add/remove classes as you see fit at the end of the transitions

Comment: This does not work - it doesn't close the current div by clicking on it. Also please know that the is far more inside each header>div than just <p> tags - there are also other divs, img, and more accordions.

Comment: This is making it so one div is always open - after you click on a header you can't close it - all of them need to be able to be able to be closed at the same time.

Comment: please verify that you are looking at latest version: http://jsfiddle.net/blurfus/9TT2t/3/   let me know if that's the version you are talking about (the behaviour I see is different from what you are describing so I just want to double-check)

Comment: you can also replace the selectors from `.accordiandiv p` to `.accordiandiv div` if you need it later in the future

Comment: Thank you! That works - sorry the fiddle I saw was not the updated one . By changing to .accordion p to .accordian .expandable it worked (I classed the divs that needed the script so it left others alone)

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
    $('.accordiandiv .expandable').hide();
    $('.accordiandiv').on('click', function () {
        $('.accordiandiv .expandable').slideUp(200, "linear", function () {
            $('.accordiandiv h3').removeClass('active');
        });
        var isVisible = $(this).find('.expandable').is(':visible');
        if (!isVisible) {
            $(this).find('.expandable').slideDown(200, "linear", function () {
                $(this).closest('.accordiandiv').find('h3').addClass('active');
            });
        }
    });    
});

Comment: I've got it working perfectly for the question asked, thank you, thank you! It's not working for the accordion nested within the accordion though, but then that is another question, I suppose.

Comment: no problem, glad to be of help...  Yes, nested accordions will have to be handled slightly differently (depending on the hierarchy)

Answer (score 1):

You can reduce your code to this:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('p').hide();
    $('.accordiandiv header').click(function () {
        var paragraph = $(this).closest('.accordiandiv').find('p');
        $('p').not(paragraph).slideUp();
        paragraph.slideToggle();
    })
});
```

**[Fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/AUteu/)**

Comment: This does not work - all but the first div are now stuck open and can't open the first div. Need the whole div to collapse not just the <p> tags.

Comment: @user3362950 I think if you just leave the selector at .closest('.accordiandiv') for paragraph, $('.accordiandiv').not(paragraph).slideUp() then you should be in good shape.

Answer (score 0):

You're unconditionally setting the state to active. There needs to be a case that doesn't do that. If you've just clicked a a div and it's open, there needs to be a condition that doesn't set state to active.

Here's the verbose version of your click() function, but I'm sure it can be made smaller (untested sorry!):

```
tis.click(function() {
      var openThis = state;
      state = !state;
      answerAll.slideUp(state);
      $('.accordiandiv').nextAll('header.active').removeClass('active');
      if (openThis) {
        answer.slideToggle(true);
        tis.toggleClass('active', true);
      }
    });
```

Comment: Could you explain this a bit more?

Comment: Essentially: slide everything up.  If the current div was up, slide it down; if it wasn't up, do't do anything (leave it up).